# How to get first and last record of every month in Sqlite

Tags: java, sqlite

in my java application I have stored candlestick data in a sqlite database (I'm new in sqlite language). The database contains one table for each stock with columns: date,open,high,low,close.
In order to display monthly candles I need a ResultSet storing first and last value for every month, max value of high and min value of low.
I was able to retrieve last two data by:

```
SELECT STRFTIME("%Y-%m", date/1000,'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS Date, max(high) AS High, min(low) AS Low
```

For the first needed data I tried to reach records :

```
where strftime('%m', date/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')<>strftime('%m', date/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime','+1 day')
```

but if the last record in month stops for example in 2015-10-29 the query skips obviously this month because +1 day is 2015-10-30

How can I make it correctly?
Thanks to all

EDIT:
entire query for last monthly value of 'close':

```
    SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', data/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS data, close from SP_500 where strftime('%m', data/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')<>strftime('%m', data/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime','+1 day') order by data desc
GROUP BY STRFTIME("%Y-%m", data/1000,'unixepoch', 'localtime')
```

EDIT 2: for anybody interested working code (thanks to CL.) is:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', max(data) / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as data,
       (SELECT open
        FROM SP_500 AS T
        WHERE T.data = MIN(SP_500.data)
        GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m', T.data / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
       ) AS month_open,
       max(high) AS month_high,
       min(low) AS month_low,
       (SELECT close
       FROM SP_500 AS T
       WHERE T.data = MAX(SP_500.data)
       GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m', T.data / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')  
       ) AS month_close
FROM SP_500
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m', data / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
ORDER BY data DESC
```

Comment: Isn't there a group by month missing? Show the entire queries.

Comment: yes but the command: GROUP BY STRFTIME("%Y-%m", data/1000,'unixepoch', 'localtime') does not give first open and last close

Comment: Show the entire queries.

Comment: Query for last close in every month: SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d', data/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as data, close from SP_500
where
strftime('%m', data/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')<>strftime('%m', data/1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime','+1 day')
order by data desc GROUP BY STRFTIME("%Y-%m", data/1000,'unixepoch', 'localtime')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first and last records in each month are the records with the smallest/largest `date` values:

```sql
SELECT strftime(..., MIN(date) / 1000, ...) AS first_date,
       strftime(..., MAX(date) / 1000, ...) AS last_date,
       ...
FROM SP_500
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m', date / 1000, ...);
```

To get the corresponding values, you need subqueries:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT open
        FROM SP_500 AS T
        WHERE T.date = MIN(SP_500.date)
       ) AS month_open,
       (SELECT close
        FROM SP_500 AS T
        WHERE T.date = MAX(SP_500.date)
       ) AS month_close,
       ...
FROM SP_500
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m', date / 1000, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was searching for dates. But now how can I subquery for relative values? I mean: now I have rows such 'date open, high, low, date close'. How can I convert 'date open' and 'date close' to values at open and close? My actual code is: SELECT  strftime('%Y-%m-%d', MAX(data)/ 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')as data,
 strftime('%Y-%m-%d', MIN(data) / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS open,
 max(high) as high,
 min(low) as low,
        strftime('%Y-%m-%d', MAX(data) / 1000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS close

Comment: Great, it works now adding grouping in every subquery. Thanks a lot